# In modal popup - get the value between LI

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul id='FileList'>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
  <li>Fifth</li>
</ul>

$("#FileList li").click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Inside modal popup, How can I alert the id of the li item clicked 
In normal HTML page, the above code works fine, but i could not able to get the value when the same div in modal popup

Thanks in advance
Bharani

Comment: Try event delegation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: how does this popup opened? is it created in real time or is it a static html that is displayed when needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try this way? :

```
$(document).on('click','#FileList li',function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```